# Integration of angularjs plugin into Zend Studio

Tags: angularjs, zend-studio

I am trying to add Angularjs into Zend Studio for mobile development. 
After finding my requirement in google i have found some links-
1) http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio-12.5/zend-studio.htm#angularjs.htm
2) http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio-12.5/zend-studio.htm#customizing_zend_studio_using_the_welcome_page.htm

But these can't help me to add angular in my project.

Then i have manually added angular js, but it did nothing.

Comment: Welcome to SO. As you were able to search for your requirements I highly encourage you to read the [SO-Guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to ask a question. Otherwise you won't get appropriate answers here.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved. Zend 11 doesn't support Angular JS. To get AngularJS support I have installed Zend 12.5/13.